# I can't remove cmd association extension in windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd

I've tried almost everything and nothing works

I clicked on make defauls association to win console cmd over a .rb file and now it is impossible to change.

what can i do to fix it ?

[one image have more value than 1000 words](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7wkd9oer105xbzh/f.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch RegEdit and navigate to:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts

Search for your extension .rb and remove it.  You should then be able to reset it as you desire.